# How do you avoid full compilation with gyp?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, compiler-warnings, node-addon-api

I'm getting started with the `node-addon-api' and while my code does compile and run, I do get the following warning:

```
Generating code
  Previous IPDB not found, fall back to full compilation.
  All 303 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
  Finished generating code
```

Indeed, everything gets recompiled when I run the command (`node-gyp rebuild -j max`) and it is kind of slow, so avoiding a recompilation of all the files would be welcome, especially when the project becomes bigger.

All I could find was [this page](https://blog.csdn.net/tytok/article/details/98069746), but adding that flag didn't do anything (either under `cflags`, `cflags_cc` or `msvs_settings`). Here is my `binding.gyp`:

```
{
    "targets": [{
        "target_name": "template",
        "cflags!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
        "cflags_cc!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
        "sources": [
            "src/cpp/wrapper.cpp",
            "src/cpp/functionexample.cpp"
        ],
        'include_dirs': [
            "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"
        ],
        'libraries': [],
        'dependencies': [
            "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
        ],
        'defines': [ 'NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS' ],
        'msvs_settings': {
            'VCCLCompilerTool': { "ExceptionHandling": 1, 'AdditionalOptions': [ '-std:c++20' ] }
        }
    }]
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rebuild` is supposed to recompile everything from scratch - you are looking for `build`

`rebuild` runs `clean`, `configure`, and `build`:

- `clean` removes the build directory if it exists <- wipes out previously compiled objects
- `configure` generates project build files for the current platform
- `build` invokes make/msbuild.exe and builds the native addon

`build` compares the old build with the your source code, finds the changes, and rebuilds only the changed code - that being said `build` is not always perfect so an occasional `rebuild` maybe needed

[source node-gyp readme](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#commands)